# Change text on "Create new Account" button makes administration created user registration fail

Tags: 7, users, forms

In the form provided by `user_registration_form()`, I modified the text for the "Create New Account" button to "Sign me up!" via the following code:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Sign me up!');
```

Creating a new account as anonymous user from the main site works fine: new button text, customized validation and submission included. Now, if I want to create a new user as administrator via "People -> 'Add User'," the form and button are correctly displayed, but NOTHING happens once I hit the button! Somehow, all validation and submission routines seem to be deactivated by renaming this button. Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: This is actually a bug in core http://drupal.org/node/208790

Comment: Since this is a bug in Drupal, I am going to close this question.

Comment: The problem is still there in Drupal 7.28!! Amazing! Did you find another way to do it since this post?

Comment: No, but I have not really tried it anymore...

Answer (score 1):

That code works without a problem for me. I hope you didn't change the code in Drupal's user module directly?

You should make this change by implementing [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in your own custom module or theme.

```
function MODULENAME_form_user_register_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
     //your changes here
   }
```

Comment: I used hook_form_alter() and did not modify the Drupal code directly! I am surprised that it works for you, but thanks for your feedback anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe submit and validation handlers in admin form expect specific name only.. you could profile / debug to be sure.

What u could probably do is instead of modifying label from form_alter, you could use translate inerface feature and give it desired name that way, since the label is already going through t() function.

Comment: Dear Gansbrest, could you please clarify on both points, i.e. how to best debug this issue and how to use the translate interface instead? Thanks!

Comment: It's very likely that gansbrest is right. It should be no problem to modify the translation, which leaves the whole form handling intact.